# How to create one bar plots using multiple columns and argument “split”

Tags: r, graphics, split, dataframe, boxplot

I need to create 16 [bar plots in one figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRS4O.png) (facet or split screen)for scientific paper from a data.frame with 17 numeric columns, and use the argument split to separate the bars by Month. I have a large data.frame for 16 evaporation methods with average monthly values. I try to do it by faceting and split screen but I could not.I have attached the image of data.I hope find solution.Best regards

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show the code you have used with (a sample of) your data, aka a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at how to reshape your data from wide to long format. Then you can use ggplot:

```
# create sample data
df <-  cbind(Month = 1:12, as.data.frame(replicate(16, runif(12))))

# reshape it from wide to long format
df <- reshape(df, idvar = 1, varying = list(-1), times = names(df)[-1], direction = "long", sep = "", timevar = "key", v.names = "value")

# Facetted bar plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Month, y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~key)
```